# How to go from a DAG model to bounded treewidth?

Tags: graph-theory, treewidth

I am cross posting this question from [CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19467/how-to-go-from-a-dag-model-to-bounded-treewidth) since I believe it is research-related question.

Given a Bayesian Network DAG $G$, we can transform it into a junction tree $T_G$ by performing two steps:

1. moralisation (connect variables that have the same child, drop directions)
2. triangulation (fill-in edges) i.e chordal graphs.

Are there known conditions/assumptions over $G$ under which for any junction tree $T_G$, $T_G$ will have tree width at most $k$? In other words, bounded treewidth for the triangulated graph of $G$?

Comment: As i understand your conditions, Complete graph satisfies this condition and is not of bounded tree width.

Comment: @Saeed I am looking for conditions to bound the tree width of any junction tree resulted from the DAG $G$. I thought about bounding the in-degree of $G$, however, this seems to be a lower bound on the resulted tree width.

Comment: Triangulation is the same as chordalization (i.e., complete a graph to a chordal graph), and the treewidth of a graph is actually the minimum, over chordalizations, of the width of the chordalization, which is the size of the maximal clique size in the chordalization minus one (see e.g., http://digitalarchive.maastrichtuniversity.nl/fedora/get/guid:e5729e4d-247c-431d-b1ce-db84ca580e53/ASSET1 p17). So once $G$ was moralized, letting $w$ be the width of the moralization, the *best* junction tree has width $w$. As for the width of the *worst* chordalization, I don't know.